# How can I calculate the median of a range of numbers that I input?

Tags: python, python-3.x, median

I want to calculate the median of a range of numbers I input. The range should be between 1 and n+1 (n is the input in my case). I made some research and saw that you can use the inbuild statistics.median. But I can't make it work.

```
import.statistics
n = int(input("Please input your number: "))
range_1 = range(1, n+1)
list_1 = list(range_1)
```

I created a list with all values between 1 and n+1 and now I want to calculate the median.

```
print(statistics.median(list_1))
```

This is my error I don't know how to print the median. What am I doing wrong? I can feel that it's really simple. Thank you for your help.

Comment: if you know `numpy` you can do `np.median([*range(1,50)])` very easy.

Comment: just find n+1/2, `print('Median:',(n+1)/2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this.

```
import statistics

number = int(input("enter the number :"))
range1 = list(range(1, number+1))
median1 = statistics.median(range1)
print("Median of the given range is :", median1)
```

Comment: Bro you saved my life it's so simple man. I didn't know you had do input that % infront of the statistics to print it. Thank you very much. The answer is answered!

Comment: Good to know. If it helped, please accept the answer by clicking the grey tick under the vote sign. Thanks.

Comment: @MarekSczokowzky That `%` is the Python2 string format operator that still works in Python3

Comment: @AbhishekRai No need to use `()` if you only have 1 argument to format